How do I refer to a union field named 'struct' in gdb
I'm debugging a zig binary where there is a union with the following fields:
>>> p value.payload.
fun     i32     only    ref     repr    string  struct  union

Most of these are fine, but I can't refer to the 'struct' field. Presumably 'struct' is a keyword in the gdb expression language.
>>> p value.payload.i32
$4 = -139623936

>>> p value.payload.struct
A syntax error in expression, near `struct'.

How can I print this field?

Isn't struct a keyword in zig as well?

It is, but you can use it as a field name anyway https://gist.github.com/jamii/1ad174ef6a0f0cd892154cc152aea0c1

You might be able to do this with python, like python print(gdb.parse_and_eval('value.payload')['struct']).
